# Range queries in jena sparql?

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

I have created a rdf model using jena for email storage..My code for thr rdf is :

```
Resource mail= model.createResource(msg.getMessageID())
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.SUBJECT, subjec)  
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.TO,receiveraddr)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.FROM,senderaddr)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.REC_NAME,receivername)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.SEND_NAME,sendername)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.ENCODING,encod)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.CONTENT,cont)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.DATE,dat)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.FOLDER_NAME,foldername)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.UID,uid)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.IN_REPLYTO,replyto)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.IN_REPLYTONAME,replyname)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.CC,cc)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.BCC,bcc)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.MAIL_SIZE,msize)  //here
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.ATTACHEMENT_NAME,filename)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.ATTACHEMENT_NO,nos)
            .addProperty(EMAILRDF.CONTENT_TYPE,msg.getContentType());
```

I have converted the MAIL_SIZE which is in integer to string to store it as a property of the rdf .Now I want to perform range queries based on the mail size :

```
SELECT ?resource
WHERE
  {
    ?resource <MAIL_SIZE:> ?size .
    FILTER (?size >= 24)
  }
```

but this query gives error ...I know that its due to the fact that I stored the MAIL_SIZE as property but I don't know how to do this ? Correct me if I am wrong I am really new to this thing ? 
**EDITS:**
PS: I have created my own set of properties.

//To define all the properties needed to make the rdf of the email

```
package email;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;


public class EMAILRDF {
    //Create a default model
    private static Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

    //Subject of the mail
    public static final Property SUBJECT = m.createProperty("SUB:" );
    //Sender of the mail
    public static final Property FROM = m.createProperty("FROM:" );
    //Receiver of the mail
    public static final Property TO  = m.createProperty("TO:" );
    //Return path
    public static final Property RETURN_PATH = m.createProperty("RETURNPATH:" );
    //main contents of the mail
    public static final Property CONTENT = m.createProperty("CONTENT:" );
    //format of the mail
    public static final Property FORMAT = m.createProperty("FORMAT:" ); 
    //content type like html etc
    public static final Property CONTENT_TYPE = m.createProperty("CONTENTTYPE:" );
    //encoding in bits
    public static final Property ENCODING = m.createProperty("ENCODING:" );
    //date of the email
    public static final Property DATE = m.createProperty("DATE:" );      
    //CC of email   
    public static final Property CC = m.createProperty("CC:" ); 
    //BCC of email  
    public static final Property BCC = m.createProperty("BCC:" ); 
    //NAME OF THE SENDER
    public static final Property ATTACHEMENT_NAME = m.createProperty("ATTACHEMENTNAME:" );
    public static final Property ATTACHEMENT_NO = m.createProperty("ATTACHEMENTNO:" );   
    //SIZE OF MAIL  
    public static final Property MAIL_SIZE = m.createProperty("MAILSIZE:" );   
    //SIZE OF THE ATTACHEMENT of email  
    public static final Property ATTACHEMENT_SIZE = m.createProperty("ATTACHEMENTSIZE:" );   
    //MAIL TO WHICH PARTICULAR MAIL HAVE REPLIED    
    public static final Property IN_REPLYTO = m.createProperty("REPLIEDTO:" );
    public static final Property IN_REPLYTONAME = m.createProperty("REPLIEDTONAME:" );
    //FOLDER IN WHICH email EXISTS  
    public static final Property FOLDER_NAME = m.createProperty("FOLDERNAME:" );   
    //UID of email  
    public static final Property UID = m.createProperty("UID:" );   
   //name os receiver of email  
    public static final Property REC_NAME = m.createProperty("RECIEVERS_NAME:" );   
   //name of sender of email    
    public static final Property SEND_NAME = m.createProperty("SENDER_N AME:" );   





   }
```

This is my code for querying the rdf model . In this I am taking input from command line but yeah string s query also works...

```
public class test4query extends Object {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        String s;
        //load the dataset 
        //String query1; 
        //query1="hjcooljohny75@gmail.com";
        //query1 = (String)(subjectentry.getText());
          //  String s="SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x <TO:> '"+query1+"'}";

        String directory = "MYDATABASES/DATA2" ;
        Dataset ds = TDBFactory.createDataset(directory) ;
        Model model = ds.getDefaultModel() ;
        ds.begin(ReadWrite.READ) ;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter a string");

            s = in.nextLine();
             //executeCmd(s) ;
            //UpdateAction.parseExecute(s,model);
            Query q =QueryFactory.create(s);
            QueryExecution qExec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(s, ds) ;
            //ResultSet rs = qExec.execSelect() ;
             QueryExecUtils.executeQuery(q, qExec) ;
         //   try {   
              //      ResultSetFormatter.out(rs) ;
               // } finally { qExec.close() ; }

            // Another query - same view of the data.

    }
}
```

and this shows the query working :

```
Enter a string
SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x <TO:> "hjcooljohny75@gmail.com" }
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| x                                                                                    |
========================================================================================
| <<SEMA-CR-3-4MHV9RJ@bounce.oracle-mail.com>>                                         |
| <<20140526171614.1F2D61314F66@elabs10.com>>                                          |
| <<5833594959587942@mjinn.com>>                                                       |
| <<5x6p1e.hvnsvp7fhgxyo04mt@mail.payback.in>>                                         |
```

Comment: your filter is fine, but you're not writing the property correctly at all.  It should be something like `<http://.../MAIL_SIZE>`, for whatever the URI of the property is.

Comment: If you want to query with `filter ( ?size >= 24 )`, you'll also want to make sure that you're storing the property as a number.  E.g., with `addLiteral( EMAIL_SIZE, msize )` where `msize` is some sort of number.

Comment: my Uri of the property is correct...and thats what I am asking ...do I have to change it to addliteral instead of addProperty()....does the range filters doesn't work if the variable is added through addproperty()?

Comment: You've got `<MAIL_SIZE:>` in your query, and I **very** strongly doubt that that's what you want.  If you try to parse that with Jena, you'll get an error like `org.apache.jena.iri.impl.IRIImplException: <MAIL_SIZE:> Code: 0/ILLEGAL_CHARACTER in SCHEME: The character violates the grammar rules for URIs/IRIs.`

Comment: As to using a number:  yes, if you want to query with `filter ( ?size >= 24 )`, use `addLiteral( EMAILRDF.MAIL_SIZE, msize )` where `msize` is a variable of some numeric type (e.g., `int`, `long`, etc.).

Comment: You can use addProperty, but you said that you "converted the MAIL_SIZE which is in integer to string to store it as a property of the rdf".  If you want to use addProperty, then you need to create the typed literal yourself, but it's easier to just use addLiteral which will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joshua!!How can i convert it to typed literal?

Comment: Creating properties like `m.createProperty("DATE:" );` is a bad idea.  Have you tried to write out or your model or parse any queries?  Something like `DATE:` isn't a legal URI.  The query parsers will reject it.  You might not be able to serialize your model.  Pick a URI prefix and use it.  Otherwise your data isn't really all that useful outside of your single application.

Comment: Why not just use addLiteral?

Comment: Well other queries are working fine!!I am just curious how can I do it in some other way...but yes, no specific reason for not using addliteral..

Comment: What version of Jena are you using?  if you try this code: `QueryFactory.create( "select * where { ?x <MAIL_SIZE:> ?msize }" );` you'll get the error `com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Line 1, column 21: org.apache.jena.iri.impl.IRIImplException: <MAIL_SIZE:> Code: 0/ILLEGAL_CHARACTER in SCHEME: The character violates the grammar rules for URIs/IRIs.`  If you're not getting that now, you probably will later when you update.

Comment: jena 2.11.1 ..and all other queries are working fine..you have to import the email package then there would be no errors!!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the packages I'm importing;  I'm simply parsing the query that *you* put in the question: `select ?resource where { ?resource <MAIL_SIZE:> ?size . }`.  *Parsing* the query doesn't have anything do with the code that generates the model.  `MAIL_SIZE:` isn't a legal URI or IRI.  If you use it in a model and try to write the model, you'll get an error like `com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.BadURIException: Only well-formed absolute URIrefs can be included in RDF/XML output: <MAIL_SIZE:> Code: 0/ILLEGAL_CHARACTER in SCHEME: The character violates the grammar rules for URIs/IRIs.`

Comment: Actually I don't know much and I am novice to this but this simply works for me!!

Comment: You haven't shown any code that actually runs a query, though, or even adds these resources to a model.  Please show a *complete*, but *minimal* example that shows a query running.

Comment: I am adding the code for querying in my question..

Answer (score 0):

I asked a question that I feel is very related, on how to use integers with Jena instead of strings so that I could query and filter on these integers. I got a helpful answer and I think it could be useful to you as well.

[Adding age (integer literals) to Jena RDF triples, and querying on them with SPARQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426559/adding-age-integer-literals-to-jena-rdf-triples-and-querying-on-them-with-spa)