# Adding age (integer literals) to Jena RDF triples, and querying on them with SPARQL

Tags: java, oracle, rdf, sparql, jena

I'm trying to learn the basics of working with Jena and RDF Triples. Also working with an Oracle database, so following their guide I have some sample programs running, such as [Example7-18  SPARQL OPTIONAL Query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11828/sem_jena.htm#RDFRM280). The example works fine as written. It allows for matching queries such as

```
where {?s <u:parentOf> ?o}

where {<u:John> <u:parentOf> <u:Mary>}
```

What I'd like to do is give John, Mary and Jill an age each, so that I can query and filter on age as described in [SPARQL By Example: The Cheat Sheet](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lapalme/ift6281/sparql-1_1-cheat-sheet.pdf), page 10:

```
A . B . FILTER ( …expr… )

where {?s <u:parentOf> ?o . ?o <u:isAge> ?a . filter ( ?a < 20 ) }
```

With the current code for triples I can only add strings/URI Nodes, and although I could make a triple such as `<u:John> <u:isAge> <u:35>`,  I cannot filter and make comparisons with, e.g., the < operator on that age, so it is not very useful.

I've been looking around for a while now and I suspect that doing this is very simple but code samples have been hard to find.

Comment: Note that text like `<u:John> <u:isAge> <u:35>` is treated as markup in the editor, so you need to surround it in backticks `\``, or else no one can see it. I've fixed it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you want an object like `"35"^^xsd:int` or `"35^^xsd:integer`, which are literals, not `<u:35>` which is a (perhaps malformed) URI.  The example is, in my opinion, doing things in a somewhat unusual way, and according to the documentation, it's using some deprecated methods.  At any rate, you can see that its creating URI nodes with methods from the [Node](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/graph/Node.html) class (a factory class):

```
Node.createURI("u:John")
Node.createURI("u:parentOf")
Node.createURI("u:Mary")
```

There are five createLiteral methods in the Node class, and you could use [createLiteral(String lex, RDFDatatype dtype)](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/graph/Node.html#createLiteral%28java.lang.String,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.RDFDatatype%29) to create a literal with a datatype.  That method is deprecated though, and you really should be using one of the methods from [NodeFactory](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/graph/NodeFactory.html) instead.

All that said, I don't know if there's any reason that the example uses the graph interface for creating triples rather than the Model interface.  You've already got a model from:

```
ModelOracleSem model = ModelOracleSem.createOracleSemModel(oracle, szModelName);
```

and this task is much easier to do if you use the [Model](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html) interface, where you have methods like [createTypedLiteral](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#createTypedLiteral%28java.lang.Object%29) so that you can simply call `createTypedLiteral(30)` and get back a suitable literal.  Here's an example:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;

public class CreateAndQueryExample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // You should be able to replace this with the Oracle model 
        // producing code.
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

        Resource john = model.createResource( "urn:ex:John" );
        Resource mary = model.createResource( "urn:ex:Mary" );
        Property age = model.createProperty( "urn:ex:age" );

        // Using Model.add method
        model.add( john, age, model.createTypedLiteral( new BigInteger( "25" )));  // "25"^^xsd:integer
        // model.add( john, age, model.createTypedLiteral( 25 ));                  // "25"^^xsd:int
        // model.add( john, age, model.createTypedLiteral( 25l ));                 // "25"^^xsd:long

        // Using the Resource.addProperty method
        mary.addProperty( age, model.createTypedLiteral( new BigInteger( "35" )));

        Query query = QueryFactory.create( "select * where { ?s <urn:ex:age> ?age . filter ( ?age < 30 ) }" );
        QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.create( query, model );
        ResultSetFormatter.out( exec.execSelect() );
    }
}
```

```
-----------------------
| s             | age |
=======================
| <urn:ex:John> | 25  |
-----------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but you left out the '<parentOf>' relationships between Resources. Would you add them also with model.add as if they were literals? What difference does it make if I add my relationships as literals or as triples?

Comment: @user985366 I didn't leave them out.  Your question asked abtou **Adding age (integer literals) to Jena RDF triples, and querying on them with SPARQL** and this answer shows how to do both of those things.  You already have a way of adding creating URI nodes, and if you want to do it using the Model interface and related interfaces, the answer has links to those interfaces.

Comment: If you're going to write a pattern like `?s :parentOf ?o . ?o :hasAge ?a`, then parentOf has to be a relationship between resources (i.e., blank nodes and URI nodes, but not literals).  Literals can't be the subject of triples, so if you used a literal in parentOf, e.g., `:John :parentOf "Mary"`, you're out of luck in the second triple, because you can't say `"Mary" :hasAge 25`.